# What flags used to get next line data into xml file using python 2.X

Tags: regex, xml, python-2.7

Im trying to convert simple .txt file to .xml file.

**Input .txt file data:** `(/tmp/abc/**sample.txt**)`

```
         Current Date:
                 19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30
```

**Output .xml should be:**

```
<Current Date> 19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30 </Current Date>
```

**My Code is:**

```
import re

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

rex = re.compile(r'''(?P<title>Curren\s+Date)\s*:\n(?P<value>.*)''')

with open('/tmp/abc/sample.txt') as f:

    for line in f:

        m = rex.search(line)

        if m:

            print m.group('title')
            print m.group('value')
            title = m.group('title')

            e = ET.Element(title)
            e.text = m.group('value')
            e.tail = '\n\n'
ET.dump(e)
```

Its not working, need to tune in re.compile pattern and flags:

```
re.compile(r'''(?P<title>Curren\s+Date)\s*:\n(?P<value>.*)''')
```

Comment: There are other problems but check your spelling... `Curren\s+Date` needs a t.

Comment: `<Current Date>` is not valid XML. Tags cannot contain spaces. Do you have a better tag name?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to capture the date string. You can do that with a `findall` (or `finditer`). Combine that with a MULTILINE flag and you are almost there.

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc = ET.Element('dates')

with open('filename') as f:
    for date in re.finditer(r'Current\s+Date\s*:.*\n\s*([^\n]+)',
        f.read(), re.MULTILINE):
        ET.SubElement('current_date').text = date

print(ET.tostring(doc))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# with open('filename') as f:
#     text = f.read()                # read file as a string, not line
text = """Current Date:
        19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30
        Current Date:
        19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30
        Current Date:
        19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30
        Current Date:
        19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30"""

import re
for i in re.finditer(r'(\w+ \w+):\n\s+([\d:]+)', text):
    xml = '<{tag}>{data}</{tag}>'.format(tag=i.group(1), data=i.group(2))
    print(xml)
```

out:

```
<Current Date>19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30</Current Date>
<Current Date>19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30</Current Date>
<Current Date>19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30</Current Date>
<Current Date>19:11:2016:09:19:00:70:30</Current Date>
```

Comment: next time vote me down, please show me the better code. vote is cheap, show me the code!